# how to make setblock a command block with a command that is executed at a certain player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have made a minigame on my server, mctrees.net, using command blocks but it dosen't work with multiplayer so I would like to make it place the commands that run for the game but for it to make it specific to each player.
e.g. I have a command that usually gets run:

```
/setblock @p[r=10] dirt ~ ~10 ~
```

and I would like to make it setblock that command in a command block when a player (trebor97351) starts the game. it should setblock a command block with the command:

```
/setblock trebor97351[r=10] dirt ~ ~10 ~
```

How would I do this?
I know that you can place command blocks with prefilled commands but you can't specify a player when doing that?

Comment: If u use /Sudo {name} {command with out \} will make them run the command, I believe it is still dependent on permission though.  Since it's a server you could just find a plugin to do it instead

Comment: @Juconah That command can only be used if you have a specific plugin.

Comment: you are all saying i should use a plugin, but what plugin do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

By the way, unless you have a mod changing this, the syntax for `/setblock` has no player selectors. You can, however, use `/execute`, along with `[name=]`, to accomplish this:

```
/execute @p[r=10,name=<username>] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~10 ~ minecraft:dirt
```

Answer (score 0):

make a certain score. for example `apply`

then try this

`execute @a[score_apply_min=0,score_apply=0] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~10 ~ minecraft:dirt`

`score_apply_min=0` tests for players with a score of 0 as minimum

`score_apply=0` (must be with `score_apply_min=0`) acts as the maximum value for the score `apply`.